# Angular Material 2 - Tooltips not shown properly

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-material, angular-material2

I use Angular2 together with Angular Material 2.

In Material 2 you have [tooltips](https://material.angular.io/components/component/tooltip). However, I'm not able to show the tooltips properly. If you hover over the trigger the tooltips are shown but than disappear immediately, are shown again and so on.

See this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/rUfWLRu87zXc5b5WwftL?p=preview) for detail. I want to achieve the behavior in the [official documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/component/tooltip).

The problem is the CSS (specially the `display` values). However, I want to keep the CSS-values provided in the plunker.

**CSS**

```
.input-group {
    display: table;
}

.input-group-addon {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    width: 1%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: table-cell;
}

.form-control {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    font-size: 14;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="input-group">

  <span class="input-group-addon">de</span>

  <input class="form-control"/>

  <span class="input-group-addon"
    [mdTooltip]="'A long text is required in de'"
    mdTooltipPosition="before">
    Hover me!
  </span>

</div>
```

Do you have any idea? Is this a bug in my code or in Material's code?

Comment: It seems to be working in the current version of Angular Material 2

Answer (score 1):

**use the script as below this should work eventually ::.

```
<span class="input-group-addon" md-tooltip="tooltip" 
title="'A long text is required in de'"
mdTooltipPosition="before">
```

Answer (score 0):

HammerJS must be installed for the tooltip to display correctly.  Make sure HammerJS is installed in your package.json.

```
npm i -S hammerjs
```

Then it must be imported into your app.module.ts.  Just importing the package into app.module worked for me.

```
import 'hammerjs';
```

I did not need to include it in the imports array of app.module.  This worked for me using Angular Material 2.0.0-beta.2 and hammerjs 2.0.8.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me. The behavior is still the same.

Comment: Are you using a prebuilt theme?  Mine did not work until I added a prebuilt or custom theme.

Comment: I'm using a prebuild theme.